# Number fields ordered by discriminant

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, geometry-of-numbers, heights, discriminant

Since the discriminant of a number field $K \neq \mathbb{Q}$ is bounded from below by an exponential of the degree $[K:\mathbb{Q}]$, for instance by Minkowski's Geometry of Numbers bound, there are finitely many number fields $K$ below a given discriminant bound $|D_{K/\mathbb{Q}}| \leq X$. Let $\mathcal{S}(X)$ be that finite set.

**Question.** *What is a good guess for the order of growth of $\# \mathcal{S}(X)$ as a function of $X$? Any reasons to expect (or to doubt) that this count should be asymptotic to a regular (say, smooth) function of $X$?*

If so, what about finer statistics of number fields at large (unconstrained degrees with $|D_{K/\mathbb{Q}}|$ as the sole parameter), such as the function of typical degree $d(X) := \frac{1}{\#\mathcal{S}(X)} \sum_{K \in \mathcal{S}(X)} [K:\mathbb{Q}]$, the mean Euler-Kronecker invariant $\gamma_K$, or the mean minimum height of a generator of a random number field,
 $$
h := \lim_{X \to \infty} \frac{1}{\#\mathcal{S}(X)}\sum_{K \in \mathcal{S}(X)} \min_{\alpha: \, K = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)} h(\alpha) \in [0,\infty].
$$
Assuming this extended number $h$ exists, should it be $0$, $\infty$, or a positive finite number? The former alternative would mean that when number fields are ordered by discriminant, a random one can be generated by a root of an integer polynomial whose coefficients are asymptotically sub-exponential in the degree. The second alternative would mean that a typical number field is complicated to describe, in the sense of requiring super-exponentially large coefficients to write down a generating element. The third alternative says simply that typical number fields have Bogomolov's height gap property.

Comment: Do you know about the known results where the degree is fixed, such as the Davenport–Heilbronn results and the more recent [results for quintics](http://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v172-n3-p02-p.pdf)?

Comment: @GregMartin: Yes, and so we have a certain linear (conjectured) asymptotic in $X$ in every fixed degree. The unconstrained degrees case seems like generally a wholly different world, e.g. all of the further questions I highlighted are meaningless in the bounded degree regime. That is unless it somehow turns out that the large degree fields make a negligible contribution to the count. For a modest start, perhaps one could limit to answering even this: does $\#\mathcal{S}(X)/X$ tend to infinity with $X$? Certainly the simple radicals $\sqrt[n]{b}$ generate only an $O(X)$ number of fields.

Comment: If I understand correctly, Conjecture 1.2 of Manjul's paper "Mass Formulae for Extensions of Local Fields, and Conjectures on the Density of Number Field Discriminants" suggests that the limit as $X$ goes to infinity of the number of degree $n$ $S_n$ fields with discriminant $\leq X$ divided by $X$ decreases rapidly with $n$. Indeed, it goes like $r_2(S_n)/ (2 \cdot n!) \prod_{d=2}^{\infty} \zeta(d)$ where $r_2(S_n)$ is the number of $2$-torsion elements of $S_n$.

Comment: This suggests an answer, but first one has to (1) see if this holds for small $X$ relative to $n$ and (2) generalize to arbitrary groups.

Comment: @WillSawin: Thanks, I also thought that the sum of the fixed degree asymptotic coefficients might be rapidly convergent. Perhaps the $\neq S_n$ groups would make a negligible (sub-dominant) count. Interesting what may actually be proved, e.g. whether an $\ll X$ bound (if it is true) may be within reach.

Comment: Given all of the uncertainty, I'd be inclined to define $\overline{h}=\limsup_{X\to\infty}$ and $\underline{h}=\liminf_{X\to\infty}$. At least then you have two well-defined quantities in $[0,\infty]$, and if it turns out that they are not equal, that would be quite interesting, too.

Comment: Great question! If one is satisfied with upper bounds, then $\# \mathcal{S}(X) \leq \exp(c_1 \log(X) \exp(c_2 \sqrt{\log\log(X)}))$, which is proved by Ellenberg-Venkatesh in the appendix to this paper: https://doi.org/10.1215/S0012-7094-07-14011-0. Using the recent advances of Couveignes and Oliver-Thorne (https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.14110), one can probably get $\# \mathcal{S}(X) \leq \exp(c_3 \log(X) \log\log(X)^2)$. I am in the process of checking that indeed all the constants appearing in Oliver-Thorne can be explicited.

Comment: P.S: I just attended a talk by Couveignes, and he mentioned Theorem 4 in his more recent preprint: https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.01759. There, he provides a construction of small models of number fields which achieves the bounds of Oliver-Thorne, with an explicit depdendency on the degree. Using this, and arguing again as done by Ellenberg-Venkatesh, one gets the bound $\# \mathcal{S}(X) \leq \exp(c_3 \log(X) \log\log(X)^2)$ that I was mentioning.